# Analize the existence of the limit in the origin for $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{x^2 + y^3} - 1}{xy - x + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve this problem:

> $$f(x,y) = \frac{e^{x^2 + y^3} - 1}{xy - x + y^2}$$

I've tried with different paths -for instance $\alpha(t) = (t,mt), \beta(t) = (t^2,0)$-, and they all led me the limit being equal to 0.

Is there something else I could try? or should I go now to prove that the limit is 0 by definition?

This is of the first problems I'm solving in this subject, sorry if it seems too basic. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this answer correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x=-y $, it gives
$$\lim_0\frac {e^{x^2-x^3}-1}{-x}=0$$

and with $x=y^2$, it becomes

$$\lim_0\frac {e^{y^4+y^3}-1}{y^3}=1$$

so, the limit does not exist.

we used the fact that
$$e^X-1\sim X \;\;(X\to 0) $$
or,  if you prefer

$$\lim_0\frac {e^X-1}{X}=1$$